# Which is the best layout to make a grid on Android?

Tags: android, layout, grid, tiles, flipboard

which is the best layout to make an app like flipboard on Android?

I need an UI that shows 6 tiles (2x3 format portrait) and it could be a list of tiles but, I need that each 6 tiles I slide the screen to see a new group of tiles. Is it better to use GridView, FrameLayout or ViewPager?

Thanks

Comment: you can use gridview for that..here is link for gridview example http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

Comment: Are you sure you want to design a layout on your own like flipboard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should go for the [FlipBoard Implementation](http://openaphid.github.io/blog/2012/05/21/how-to-implement-flipboard-animation-on-android/) which is already implemented and which provides full functionality of flipboard kind or layout.

You can also check out the [Demo](https://code.google.com/p/flipboard/source/checkout) of Flipboard layout animation. Also a library of [FlipView](https://github.com/emilsjolander/android-FlipView)

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure that I need a layout like flipboard... it's a requirement of the app

Answer (score 0):

you can use **gridview** for showing the 6 slides a 2x3. Its the best method for showing as tiles. If your each tile has different size then go for framelayout/viewpager.